# Adding Service Reference to ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have searched on here for the exact solution to my problem to no avail.

I have added a Web Service to my project but am unable to reference it. Clicking Discover works fine - the service is available but when it comes to retrieving a list of services at its location the following text appears:

> The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>
> ```
> 'http://localhost:57657/Services/AFDiscovery.svc'.
> ```
>
> If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and
>   adding the service reference again.

How do I fix this? I am attempting to run the service locally so I do **not** need to add it within IIS.

Web.config information:

```
<services>
  <service name="WebServiceInterface.AFDiscovery">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WebServiceInterface.AFDiscovery" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Is this service in the same `Solution`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - Yes.

Comment: Is the project that the service exists in building?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - Correct, the service was developed by someone else within the company but I have added the necessary files I needed I just need to reference the service to get it running.

Comment: Please post the relevant configuration information from the service project in your question. It defines how it's published. Something is wrong there.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - The Web.config project file or the .svc markup?

Comment: The `Web.config` portions that are relevant to how the service is published in the `svc` project.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - OK, I will add them to the question.

Comment: You appear to be missing the `IMetadataExchange` information--see this post on MSDN. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec8429cc-387c-4bdd-ac59-69b37313d730/wcf-help-needed-metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved-nettcplocalhost

Comment: Change from contract="WebServiceInterface.AFDiscovery" to contract="WebServiceInterface.IAFDiscovery", May be "I" missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the project containing the WebServiceInterface.AFDiscovery in your solution. Then in the project using the web service, when you add your reference, instead of clicking "Discover", use the load from project option.

If you want to load the reference via a URL (Discover button), try browsing to "`http://localhost:57657/Services/AFDiscovery.svc?WSDL`" in your browser. If you get a message saying the metadata isn't accessible, you must modify your web service web.config.

Check this link for configuring the web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751951.aspx

It should look similar to:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
     <service
      name="WebServiceInterface.AFDiscovery"
      behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">

       <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="WebServiceInterface.IAFDiscovery" />

       <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you - the error was caused by misconfiguration within Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the possibility is the service name in your Web.config does not
>   match the namespace in your class file.Make sure the names are the
>   same then try again.

[Refer](http://chanmingman.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/the-html-document-does-not-contain-web-service-discovery-information/)

And double Check your Service MarkUp code by reghclick and Choose MarkUp